# oracle regexp_substring return only part of pattern

Tags: oracle

Regexp_substr return only part of searching pattern.

```
  SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('im searching value beginning from keyword with word "number" and digits after it like number № 3 in the string',
                '(number.{0,4}\d{1,2})')

                "REGEXP_SUBSTR"
  FROM DUAL
```

Its returning "number №", without digits. However, search works fine: without "№ 3" in sample code it return none

Comment: Your query [doesn't even work for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d4cc34d0a42e327d3f7cb68617f3815f).  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: At last. Internal function depends from client settings!

Comment: There can be differences between regex tools depending on the environment.  A demo in Regex 101 is not the same as Oracle SQL's regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this funky `№` character may actually count for more than one character for Oracle. Extending `.{0,4}` to `.{0,5}` seems to work:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
      'im searching value beginning from keyword with word "number" and digits after it like number № 3 in the string',
      '(number.{0,5}\d{1,2})'
  ) "REGEXP_SUBSTR"
  FROM DUAL
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=64eb7520b4b550a1c4c8b966a089247f)**

Comment: Yes, something wrong with unicode-related area. Not works on original, but on sample is :(